# The homomorphism induced by holomorphic map preserves Hodge decomposition

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a holomorphic map between two compact Kähler manifolds. Then the induced map $f^*:H^1(Y,\mathbb{C})\to H^1(X,\mathbb{C})$ preserves the Hodge decomposition. Is there a reference for a proof of this statement? Or Can you give a proof?

In particular, can you explain what exactly does “preserves Hodeg decomposition” mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hodge decomposition is the isomorphism $H^1(Y; \mathbb{C}) \cong H^{1,0}_{\bar{\partial}}(Y)\oplus H^{0,1}_{\bar{\partial}}(Y)$. The statement just means that $f^* : H^{1,0}_{\bar{\partial}}(Y) \to H^{1,0}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)$ and $f^* : H^{0,1}_{\bar{\partial}}(Y) \to H^{0,1}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)$.

Comment: Is there a proof on some book?

Comment: @Danny: Here's the exercise you need to do. Show first that a holomorphic mapping pulls back $(p,q)$-forms to $(p,q)$-forms, and then that $\bar\partial(f^*\omega) = f^*(\partial\bar\omega)$ when $f$ is holomorphic.